# Not able to access the array which is outside the NgOnInit

Tags: angular

I am trying to access the array. Using console.log it gives undefined when I display by an index and If I display the whole it gives Array []. The values are pushed into it outside the NgOnInit that's why I am able to get newdates array but not this one.
I don't know how to do it. I need to pass those values to my graph.

`public min_temp = new Array();` 
using new Array gives me

```
Array(7)
0: 27.4
1: 28.7
2: 28.2
3: 28.9
4: 32.4
5: 30.2
6: 30.7
length: 7
```

but still undefined when I display using index

`console.log(this.newdates);`  gives

```
(7) ["2019-03-30", "2019-03-31", "2019-04-01", "2019-04-02", "2019-04-03", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-05"]
0: "2019-03-30"
1: "2019-03-31"
2: "2019-04-01"
3: "2019-04-02"
4: "2019-04-03"
5: "2019-04-04"
6: "2019-04-05"
length: 7
```

**Code:**

```
  public weatherSearchForm: FormGroup;
  public weatherData: any;
  public show = 0;
  public weatherDataNext: any;
  public weatherDataHistory: any;

  public date: Date;
  public newdates = [];
  public history_data = [];
  public min_temp = new Array();
  public max_temp = [];
  public avg_temp = [];
  chart = [];

  dataSource: Object;
  chartConfig: Object;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private apixuService: ApixuService,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,


  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      location: [""]
    });

  for (let i = 6; i >=0; i--) {
  this.date = new Date();
  this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate() - i );
  this.newdates.push(this.datePipe.transform(this.date,"yyyy-MM-dd"));

  }
        console.log(this.newdates);

    }

  sendToAPIXU(formValues) {
    this.apixuService.getWeather(formValues.location).subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherData = data;
      console.log(this.weatherData);
    });
    this.apixuService.getNextWeather(formValues.location).subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherDataNext = data;
      console.log(this.weatherDataNext);
    });
    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {    
    this.apixuService.getHistoryWeather(formValues.location,this.newdates[i-1]).subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherDataHistory = data;
      this.history_data.push(data);
      this.min_temp.push(this.weatherDataHistory.forecast.forecastday[0].day.mintemp_c);
      this.max_temp.push(this.weatherDataHistory.forecast.forecastday[0].day.maxtemp_c)
      this.avg_temp.push(this.weatherDataHistory.forecast.forecastday[0].day.avgtemp_c);

    });
    }
    console.log("Min_temp");
    console.log(this.min_temp);
    console.log(this.min_temp[1]);
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `this.apixuService.getHistoryWeather` call asynchronous, so you need move console log inside subscribe, after this line of code it run next line of code *immediately*

```
this.apixuService.getHistoryWeather(formValues.location,this.newdates[i-1]).subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherDataHistory = data;
      this.history_data.push(data);
      this.min_temp.push(this.weatherDataHistory.forecast.forecastday[0].day.mintemp_c);
      this.max_temp.push(this.weatherDataHistory.forecast.forecastday[0].day.maxtemp_c)
      this.avg_temp.push(this.weatherDataHistory.forecast.forecastday[0].day.avgtemp_c);

      console.log("Min_temp");
      console.log(this.min_temp);
      console.log(this.min_temp[1]);

    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for all the observables to be returned, before passing the `this.min_temp` data to your graph. You can make use of RxJS's [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to wait for all subscriptions to be completed.

```
const observableDataList: Observable[] = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {   
    observableDataList.push(this.apixuService.getHistoryWeather(formValues.location,this.newdates[i-1]));
}

Observable.forkJoin(observableDataList)
  .subscribe(response => {
    //console.log(response);
    // the above should print out all the data after looping through all 8 iterations
    // this.min_temp = ....
    .
    .

  });
```